# Unix : taking repeating value from a column and making a file out of it

Tags: awk, sed

For example, let's say you have a code like the one below, and you want to take the repeatings from column 2 and make a new file out of it.

```
Dog     121        234
Cat     121        222
Rate    123        256
Mouse   122        233
Hat     121        230
```

So you want everything from column 2 that has "121" and make a new file of it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Could you please edit your question to provide the output file that should be generated for the given example input?

Comment: Looks like the OP abandoned this question and asked a new one instead - [Unix separation of specific numbers from Column](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/592059/unix-separation-of-specific-numbers-from-column)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by making two passes over the file; once to count occurrences and once to print those whose counts are greater than 1:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {count[$2]++; next} count[$2] > 1' file file
Dog     121        234
Cat     121        222
Hat     121        230
```

Comment: what if it was in column 3? would the [$2] be changed to [$3] also want happens to the >1 ? thank you

Comment: @Jazzylay yes to detect duplicates in column 3 change both instances of `$2` to `$3`. The `>1` is just an arithmetic comparison, so that stays the same

Comment: thank you so much! I do have another question if you don't mind cause I'm curious what happens when there are multiple sets of duplicates for different numbers... like for example in the second column its "121, 121, 121, 134, 145,189, 145" how do you specify which duplicated number you are looking for? (if you don't mind thank you so much though!)

Comment: @Jazzylay Your question asks about extracting lines that have duplicated numbers in the second columns, not how to extract lines that has a _specific_ number in the second column. To do that, just use `awk '$2 == 121' file`. If you have further questions, consider asking new questions rather than adding followup questions in comments.