# Unix separation of specific numbers from Column

Tags: awk, sed, sort

How can I separate specific numbers from a column and add it to a new file? For example, take all numbers that are "134" from column 3, I tried using

```
awk '$3 == 134" file.txt
```

but it didn't work, also tried using

```
awk -F, '{print $3 == 134 }' file.txt
```

didn't work.

```
Pink          132           134
Blue          189           167
Yellow        2000          134
Green         678           145
Black         789           145
White         780           135
```

So the new file will contain just the following

```
Pink          132           134
Yellow        2000          134
```

Comment: Why did `awk '$3 == 134" file.txt` not work? What happened when you tried it?

Comment: ... the quotes are mismatched - that's the only issue I can see

Comment: The field separator is wrong too like I explained in my answer

Comment: @GillesQuenot Not on the first attempt.

Comment: @terdon , sorry! I did come to realize that my quotients are mismatched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
 awk '$3 == 134' file.txt | tee new_file.txt
```

As far as you don't have the `,` separator, remove `-F,` from the awk command.

And you open the command in single quote and close it with double quote

Comment: Thank you so much I saw i made silly mistakes.